# UISwipeGestureRecognizer doesn't work on presented VC and view

Tags: ios, swift, selector, uiswipegesturerecognizer, presentviewcontroller

The hierarchy:

- MainVC calls `present(GameVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`

  `let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameVC") as! GameVC
  self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`
- `GameVC` has `GameView` (subclass of `UIView`) which covers the whole VC

In the **initializer for `GameView`**, I have this code to configure the swipe gestures:

```
let leftGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(leftSwipe))
leftGesture.direction = .left
self.addGestureRecognizer(leftGesture)

let rightGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rightSwipe))
rightGesture.direction = .right
self.addGestureRecognizer(rightGesture)

let downGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(downSwipe))
downGesture.direction = .down
self.addGestureRecognizer(downGesture)
```

Corresponding selectors:

```
@objc func downSwipe() {
    //code
}

@objc func leftSwipe() {
    //code
}

@objc func rightSwipe() {
    //code
}
```

The selectors are not getting called. However, when I make `GameVC` the initial VC that is being displayed(by dragging the storyboard arrow onto `GameVC`), **the gestures work as intended.** This makes me think that calling `present()` might've messed up the hierarchy that gestures operate on, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: What is `self`? It can't be the game view controller, because VCs don't have a `addGestureRecognizer` method. `present(GameVC, animated: true, completion: nil)` is not real code as `GameVC` seems to be a type. Can you show exactly how you are presenting this VC? By "initialiser of `GameVC`", do you mean `init`, or `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Can't you use a delegation pattern? The functions  are in` GameVC` or MainVC`?

Comment: Which initialiser method do you have the code in? Try putting it in `viewDidLoad` instead

Comment: @Sweeper Ah my bad, I meant the initializer for `GameView`. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Sweeper I didn't include the details on how I presented `GameVC` because it worked as intended, but I'll add the code in my question if it helps.

Comment: Did you try to add GameView as child to root view of GameVC in viewDidLoad? I think it can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to indicate in that your gestures can be handled simultanaously by providing corresponding delegate method.

The below demo code works using above. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```swift
class GameView: UIView {
}

// in Storyboard just empty view of above custom GameView
class GameVC: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let leftGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(leftSwipe))
        leftGesture.direction = .left
        leftGesture.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftGesture)

        let rightGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rightSwipe))
        rightGesture.direction = .right
        rightGesture.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightGesture)

        let downGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(downSwipe))
        downGesture.direction = .down
        downGesture.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(downGesture)

    }

    // allows own view gestures to run with system originated simultaneously
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        true
    }

    @objc func downSwipe() {
        print(">> down swipe")
    }

    @objc func leftSwipe() {
        print(">> left swipe")
    }

    @objc func rightSwipe() {
        print(">> right swipe")
    }
}

// Initial VC, in storyboard contains only button linked to below showGame action
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func showGame(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameVC") as! GameVC
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I configure my gestures in GameView, not GameVC.

Comment: Actually, I realized that I could configure the gestures in GameVC like you said, and then call GameView methods. Thank you so much, this works perfectly! Out of curiosity, why did I need to add the gestureRecognizer callback?

Comment: @Xcoder, because with new modal presentation iOS installs own UISwipeGestureRecognizer, so they conflict.

Comment: Thank you so much! One last question: Is there any way I can disable the iOS's own swipe gestures?

Comment: @Xcoder, add `func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool` delegate method and return `true` in it. But you become responsible to close presented controller.